# Cómo convertir texto de una lista a tupla?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
   a= ["('A442', 'A563')", "('A545', 'A779')"]
```

Requiero obtener una tupla así:

```
   a = [('A442', 'A563'), ('A545', 'A779')]
```

Intente utilizar el replace para reemplazar las comillas, pero no me funciono

```
   a= [x.replace('""', '') for x in a]
```

Alguien me puede ayudar. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método más sencillo pero a su vez **más peligroso** sería `eval()`:

```
a = ["('A442', 'A563')", "('A545', 'A779')"]    
print([eval(x) for x in a])
# [('A442', 'A563'), ('A545', 'A779')]
```

Pero el uso de `eval()` es muy peligroso, ya que puede ejecutar código malicioso.

Una alternativa más segura sería.

```
print([tuple(x.replace("('", "").replace("')", "").split("', '")) for x in a])
# [('A442', 'A563'), ('A545', 'A779')]
```

Si lo mejoramos un poco podríamos usar:

```
print([tuple(x.replace("('", "").replace("')", "").replace(" ", "").split("','")) for x in a])
# [('A442', 'A563'), ('A545', 'A779')]
```

De esta forma ya no requiere de un espacio entre cada item de la tupla.

Y en caso de que no te moleste el importar módulos puedes usar [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) para reemplazar el `.replace`:

```
import re
print([tuple(re.sub("[()' ]", "", x).split(",")) for x in a])
# [('A442', 'A563'), ('A545', 'A779')]
```